# which is better, setfacl or chmod +a?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod, setfacl

I have been working with Ubuntu for a year or so.

Just the other week I have started to learn the Symfony framework which works faster with the ACL.

In the installation and configuration of Symfony ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup ) the permissions section offer two ways to set up the permissions, using setfacl or chmod +a.

It seems Ubuntu supports setfacl instead of chmod +a.

My question; is one better than the other here? ie is one more efficient

Comment: I would say that neither of them is more efficient. Regarding your link about Symfony, i would choose the 3rd solution (umask) because setfacl is an additional overlay, seems an overkill for that, and it is a bit annoying to manage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is better than the other. They accomplish the same thing. Asking if one is more efficient is like asking if the code you are writing will run more efficiently if you write it in vi or emacs. The end result is the same.

Comment: *citation needed* - just because they accomplish the same thing does not mean they have equal efficiency

Comment: They both are a command to create an ACL. The ACL will have the same "efficiency" regardless of what command created it.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clearer. Yes, the ACL will be the same regardless of how it was made, but commands used to create it can have differential performance. Just like a sorted array is the same whether it was sorted with bubble-sort or quick-sort, but the method to create it differs greatly in terms of efficiency.

Comment: For instance, the reason I found this question is because I had to set permissions on a 3TB samba share, and I wanted to know which was the fastest method.